# ListWalletDir: Access is denied D:\System Volume Information

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows

My BTC Core wallet is not yet fully synchronized, now I got this message in the debug Notepad ''List Wallet Dir: `Access is denied D:\System Volume Information'`' and whenever I move the mouse over the left tab, it stops at *open Wallet* and nothing works anymore it will not responding and I need to close the Wallet, I hate Btc core Wallet because it's my second time now I downloaded at a new Laptop and I got another Bug again.

Comment: `Access is denied` is not a bug, but the software in your system hasn't permission to write to the disk. I think that your bug is related to your system configuration.

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I have no idea what I can do, maybe you can help me

Comment: I have no idea how to change the permission on Windows, I'm linux user, try to read this post https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security-winpc/how-to-change-folder-and-file-permissions-in/783e7040-d18f-4c04-a0f3-830b4841bb68

Answer (score 1):

This long standing issue should be fixed in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21907.